# How can i get artboard information with IText7

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, itext7

When I open a [pdf file](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiH7JxRcxtAKYl1WY?e=9lYC7S) with Illustrator, I can see the artboards[screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiH9VEf89gbD8v68v?e=oahWG3). So I know it exists in the pdf file, but I can't find it. How can I get it with IText7 in the code.
I just want to get all the text of artboards.20,90,280,330,etc.

Comment: Your PDF file (like AI PDF files in general) contains a lot of information in so called **PieceInfo** dictionaries. These **PieceInfo** structures offer programs a way to store their own, private data in a PDF alongside regular PDF content. Usually the format of the contents of these private data pieces is not publicly documented. In particular I'm not aware of the AI **PieceInfo** structures being publicly documented anywhere. You may try and analyze these contents to reverse-engineer the format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no searchable text in the PDF, just illustrator graphics including images.

The thumbnails are not images as such (will not be listed as the several images used per page) they are stored as xmp img text. and query +itext extract xmpGimg (or xmp img) shows me zer0 related results? same as if you search for letters like A B C none are stored, there are no fonts thus there is no body text its a file of illustrations.

```
964XCH22034MB1511.pdf (list via a CLI tool does not include meta thumbnails)
24 images available   (note none are 256 wide)
page  obj#  id  type width height colorspace comp bpc interp   size filters
===========================================================================
   1    21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        22 Im2 image   750    175    Indexed    4   8          5 KB FlateDecode
        20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        23     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           219 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
   2    27 Im2 image   750    175    Indexed    4   8          5 KB FlateDecode
        20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        28     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           213 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
   3    31 Im0 image   750    175    Indexed    4   8          5 KB FlateDecode
        20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        32     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           213 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
   4    20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        35 Im0 image   750    175    Indexed    4   8          5 KB FlateDecode
        36     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           220 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
   5    39 Im0 image   750    175    Indexed    4   8          5 KB FlateDecode
        20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        40     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           213 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
   6    20 Im0 smask   489     95    Indexed    4   8    *     2 KB FlateDecode
        44 Im1 image  1100    190    Indexed    4   8          6 KB FlateDecode
        21 Im1 smask   698    336 DeviceCMYK    4   8        429 KB FlateDecode
        45     thumb    29     18    Indexed    3   8           213 ASCII85Decode,FlateDecode
```

So there are several ways to read or extract the text to transcode into an image, xmp base64 is a problem format for simple base64 converters as it has odd embedments so usually need cleaning to standard base 64 then the image can be reversed. see middle of this chunk

> jwKzO7tVm **`&#xA;`** ZiaknCGJ5oz

[image]

[image]

Some command line tools may be able to extract that meta data easily, but if not then a text extract and clean-up may be required.

In fact there are two copies in that file both like this
[image]

***Thus your preview in question above does not appear to be the true thumbnails but perhaps an Adobe AI runtime preview.***

Comment: Thanks.I just want to get all the text of artboards.20,90,280,330,etc.

Comment: [The marked](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiQBkLSR5tzoi4_P3?e=TmLpIx)